# Firebase Flutter: query receive null but when reload emulator works fine

Tags: firebase, flutter

In my collection, I was trying to use reference field stored collection/doc id  but it wasn't work for me or I messed it up. I decided to change field type from reference type to String type and store doc id instead.

I use Streambuilder to query to get doc id and trying to use another Streambuilder for query by the doc id that I got from first query. Error said receive null but when I reload emulator it works fine

Error and some code Pic->
[I use streambuilder inside streambuilder for query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Ebp.png)

Is there anyway to avoid nested nested Streambuilder?

Comment: Please post the streambuilder code and the error messages as text.

Comment: Don't post images, just error log and important part of the code. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StreamBuilder`, `FutureBuilder`, `async` all this methods need some time to load and can return a `null` value so, you need check this value.

```dart
...

builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    //This "??" will avoid problems if snapshot has data but "tname" is null
    return Text(snapshot.data["tname"] ?? "Default value"); 
  }
  //Add something to indicate that the value is loading or is null
  return Text("Default Value"); 
}
```